# GDAL warp Too many points failed to transform. It works with similar image and source

Tags: gis, gdal, netcdf, geo, geotiff

I am trying to convert a netCDF file from GOES Full disk to geotiff but have an error on last step.

Apparently the process of generating the tif from NC works and fulldisk.tif is generated but not georeferenced and I need it to overlay in a leaflet map.

```
gdal_translate -ot float32 -unscale -CO COMPRESS=deflate NETCDF:"fulldisk.nc":CMI fulldisk.tif
Input file size is 2500, 1500
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

The tiff can be downloaded here: https://nube1.on.gt/fulldisk.tif

But when trying to reproject for Lat,Lon  with the following process:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 -dstnodata -999.0 fulldisk.tif /var/www/nube1.on.gt/fulldisk_geo.tif
```

it says the following:

```
Processing fulldisk.tif [1/1] : 0Using internal nodata values (e.g. -1) for image fulldisk_geo.tif.
ERROR 1: Too many points (529 out of 529) failed to transform, unable to compute output bounds.
Warning 1: Unable to compute source region for output window 0,0,2500,1500, skipping.
...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

The NC file is a [GOES-16 you can download](https://noaa-goes16.s3.amazonaws.com/ABI-L2-CMIPC/2021/114/17/OR_ABI-L2-CMIPC-M6C13_G16_s20211141756132_e20211141758516_c20211141758597.nc) from AWS  and the gdalinfo output is this:

```
Driver: netCDF/Network Common Data Format
Files: fulldisk.nc
Size is 512, 512
Coordinate System is `'
Metadata:
  NC_GLOBAL#cdm_data_type=Image
  NC_GLOBAL#Conventions=CF-1.7
  NC_GLOBAL#dataset_name=OR_ABI-L2-CMIPF-M6C13_G16_s20211141750164_e20211141759483_c20211141759577.nc
  NC_GLOBAL#date_created=2021-04-24T17:59:57.7Z
  NC_GLOBAL#id=71a29d9f-02b2-44b5-81b2-73a3fec6a62e
  NC_GLOBAL#institution=DOC/NOAA/NESDIS > U.S. Department of Commerce, National Oceanic and Atmospheric Administration, National Environmental Satellite, Data, and Information Services
  NC_GLOBAL#instrument_ID=FM1
  NC_GLOBAL#instrument_type=GOES R Series Advanced Baseline Imager
  NC_GLOBAL#iso_series_metadata_id=8c9e8150-3692-11e3-aa6e-0800200c9a66
  NC_GLOBAL#keywords=SPECTRAL/ENGINEERING > INFRARED WAVELENGTHS > BRIGHTNESS TEMPERATURE
  NC_GLOBAL#keywords_vocabulary=NASA Global Change Master Directory (GCMD) Earth Science Keywords, Version 7.0.0.0.0
  NC_GLOBAL#license=Unclassified data.  Access is restricted to approved users only.
  NC_GLOBAL#Metadata_Conventions=Unidata Dataset Discovery v1.0
  NC_GLOBAL#naming_authority=gov.nesdis.noaa
  NC_GLOBAL#orbital_slot=GOES-East
  NC_GLOBAL#platform_ID=G16
  NC_GLOBAL#processing_level=National Aeronautics and Space Administration (NASA) L2
  NC_GLOBAL#production_data_source=Realtime
  NC_GLOBAL#production_environment=OE
  NC_GLOBAL#production_site=NSOF
  NC_GLOBAL#project=GOES
  NC_GLOBAL#scene_id=Full Disk
  NC_GLOBAL#spatial_resolution=2km at nadir
  NC_GLOBAL#standard_name_vocabulary=CF Standard Name Table (v35, 20 July 2016)
  NC_GLOBAL#summary=Single emissive band Cloud and Moisture Imagery Products are digital maps of clouds, moisture and atmospheric windows at IR bands.
  NC_GLOBAL#timeline_id=ABI Mode 6
  NC_GLOBAL#time_coverage_end=2021-04-24T17:59:48.3Z
  NC_GLOBAL#time_coverage_start=2021-04-24T17:50:16.4Z
  NC_GLOBAL#title=ABI L2 Cloud and Moisture Imagery
Subdatasets:
  SUBDATASET_1_NAME=NETCDF:"fulldisk.nc":CMI
  SUBDATASET_1_DESC=[5424x5424] toa_brightness_temperature (16-bit integer)
  SUBDATASET_2_NAME=NETCDF:"fulldisk.nc":DQF
  SUBDATASET_2_DESC=[5424x5424] status_flag (8-bit integer)
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,  512.0)
Upper Right (  512.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (  512.0,  512.0)
Center      (  256.0,  256.0)
```

I tested the same process with another image that is not fulldisk  from the same site and it works as expected, https://nube1.on.gt/conus_geo.tif. I need the are of Central America and the Caribbean that is in the fulldisk domain.

Thank you for any guidance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replaced

> -dstnodata -999.0

with

> -dstnodata -999

forcing the destination no data value to be integer, and got

```
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 -dstnodata -999 fulldisk.tif fulldisk_geo.tif
Processing input file fulldisk.tif.
Using internal nodata values (e.g. -1) for image fulldisk.tif.
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

with no errors and a resulting 168.1 MiB file.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason now the gdalwarp works, with -999 and -999.0. Thanks again for trying.. will post if some other findings could relate to the issue.